# Configuring PyCharm to cooperate with Peewee's external documentation

Tags: documentation, pycharm, external, peewee

I'm currently trying to make Peewee docs work inside PyCharm (Ctrl+Q).
I've tried adding following rule in settings, but it's not really working

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/search.html?q={element.name}

Is there a way to use Quick Documentation feature with Peewee docs? I'll be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial solution as a clickable link will be automatically created for you in the quick documentation to the External Documentation.

In: `Settings - Tools - Python External Documentation`
Add an entry for peewee.
 
module name=`peewee`
url=`http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#{class.name}.{function.name}`

`Shift-F1` is the default keyboard shortcut to lookup External Documentation